# Change Date format with Month name and date format in string in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two date formats 2020-01-02T10:26:47.056-04:00 and January 2, 2020, 10:10 AM that I need to transform into a comparable date format to make a subtraction between the two dates.

I've tried turning into strings and truncating them but I can't get the formatting right

FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%E*S', PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E*S', New_Date))

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have two different time formats and second one is at the same timezone as first one (offset -04:00).

- '2020-01-02T10:26:47.056-04:00'
- 'January 2, 2020, 10:10 AM'

Try this one:

```sql
SELECT DATETIME_DIFF(first, second, SECOND) elapsed_seconds FROM (
  SELECT DATETIME(TIMESTAMP('2020-01-02T10:26:47.056-04:00')) first, 
         PARSE_DATETIME('%B %e, %Y, %R %p', 'January 2, 2020, 10:10 AM') second
);
```

output:

[image]

(update)

```sql
SELECT DATETIME_DIFF(first, second, SECOND) elapsed_seconds 
  FROM (
    SELECT DATETIME(TIMESTAMP(date_answer)) first,
           PARSE_DATETIME('%B %e, %Y, %R %p', date_created) second
      FROM (
        SELECT json_value(answer, '$.date_created') as date_answer,
               date_created from table1
      )
  )
```

Above your query got an error like below, it means `date_created`   column in `table1` is a TIMESTAMP.

> "No matching signature for function PARSE_DATETIME for argument types: STRING, TIMESTAMP. Supported signature: PARSE_DATETIME(STRING, STRING) at [4:10]", "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

If so, second time format is not like `January 2, 2020, 10:10 AM` as you said. Json value is ok with `TIMESTAMP()` because it is a TIMESTAMP formatted string.
And you can convert `date_created` TIMESTAMP column in `table1` to `DATETIME` by `DATETIME(date_created) AS second` in my original query.

Comment: I'm getting a formatting error "No matching signature for function PARSE_DATETIME for argument types: STRING, TIMESTAMP. Supported signature: PARSE_DATETIME(STRING, STRING) at [4:10]", "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Comment: SELECT DATETIME_DIFF(first, second, SECOND) elapsed_seconds FROM (
  SELECT DATETIME(TIMESTAMP(date_answer)) first, 
         PARSE_DATETIME('%B %e, %Y, %R %p', date_created) second
         
         FROM (

SELECT

json_value(answer, '$.date_created') as date_answer
, date_created


from table1
)
)

Comment: Do you think it has to do with the json function?

Comment: It's because `date_created` is a `TIMESTAMP` type, not a string. You should check your columns first to figure out which one has which time format out of two.

Comment: Is there a way to change their formats? I'm not sure how to check the format type of the result of a JSON extraction.

Comment: I mean the date_created column in the `table1`, not the value which is extracted from json.

Comment: So if I extracted from a JSON and the values look like this: "2020-01-02T10:26:47.056-04:00" is there a day to transform them to be able to use them in a date format function?

Comment: I've updated my answer. check it out, please.